# Multiple pdf outputs with template

Tags: templates, automation

I have some 84 files

> `S1-5.tex, S1-6.tex, S1-7.tex, S1-8.tex, S2-1.tex, S2-2.tex` like these

which only contain content. The templ.tex file contains the preamble. I need to generate 84 pdf files with correspoding names. How to automate this?

Answer (score 1):

With [latexmk](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) you could use `latexmk *.tex` from a command line if you have all and only the files you need in one directory. (Something like this probably works with other tools too.)

To answer the question raised in the comments: each of the files will need to include the template, e.g. with `\include`. using '*.tex' will also run latexmk on the template if it's in the same directory. That could be fixed by keeping it somewhere else, or by doing something more sophisticated on the command line i.e. using a regular expression to get only the files you want.

Comment: Can you explain how a template file is used here? My sequential files contain only content not any kind of Latex preamble.

Comment: I assume your `Sn-m.tex` files each `\input` your `templ.tex` . If not, how is it used?

Comment: Yes templ.tex has files included with \input. I am running like this `latexmk -lualatex tmpl.tex`. But the output is a single file. Where as `latexmk *.tex` is not yielding anything.

Comment: It sounds as if `templ.tex` inputs the other files. I'd expected the other way - that the other files would each include the template. Please post a minimal version of your template, and a minimal version of two of the `Sn-m.tex` files.

Comment: I followed your way. I included template files in `Sn-m.tex` files. Now latexmk is doing fine.

Comment: You can answer your own question here, and accept your answer, so people will know they need not spend any more time on it.